# python implemented in assembly

Tags: python

Am just being curious but I would like to know whether python can be implemented in assembly and if not why has it not been done to help for speed issues. forgive my naivete in matters of programming languages.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/

Comment: this question is wrong on so many levels… where to begin? nobody implements complex software in assembler anymore - it's simply not manageable. and for all you know parts of python /are/ implemented in inline assembler. also, what speed issues? apart from that: yes, it can be implemented in assembler (anything can).

Comment: premature optimization is the root of all evil

Comment: @hop: Is there inline assembly in CPython (I really don't know, although from what I know most CPython optimizations don't operate on that level)? Or in some other implementation (I assume the JITs of Unladden Swallow and PyPy might)?

Comment: @delnan: i wouldn't know

Comment: I think this question does have answers -- "Yes", and "Because it is impractical, isn't portable, and is unlikely to produce a significant speed improvement." Therefore, I don't think it should be closed.

Comment: @hop: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RollerCoaster_Tycoon#History

Comment: why the downvotes? a beginner asked a good question, IMO.

Comment: @Aphex: 1. Quite a while ago, 2. An exception even back then and 3. few would be able to pull something like this off.

Comment: @Nick: well, clearly, those who downvoted must think otherwise!

Comment: I think the problem here is that you would have to explain a lot about computers, programming languages compilation and virtual machines to get an answer a beginner can actually understand - "The language semantics really dictate quite a bit about how fast (or not) a language is." is a really great answer to anyone who knows how programming languages like Python work, but it tells nothing to someone who doesn't. So this question is too broad and made me click close.

Comment: @Aphex: the operative word is "anymore."

Comment: I don't see any reason why this question is closed.  The claim that it would not have an answer is rebutted by the good answers that it got, including the one by Fred Larson above.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The main implementation is written in C, and that's compiled to machine code (i.e. assembly made readable for the CPU). So writing it assembly is certainly possible, and if it's possible for a compiler, it's possible for humans - in theory. In practice, it is not even remotely practical. Not only asm is even more low-level than C (increasing development time significantly, perhaps even expotentially to the project size), it's also highly platform-specific, so each port takes a huge lot of work (and maintaince is multiplied by the number of supported platforms - quite a few in the case of CPython).

Apart from that, it's highly questionable if this would give a notable speed bonus. Writing it closer to the metal doesn't make stuff go faster magically (the contrary can be the case - you'd be hard-pressed to find a programmer who can consistently write better assembly than the four or five well-known C compilers). And much of Python's slowness comes from the many many abstractions and indirections the language consists of, not from a sloppy implementation of these.

A more promising approach (which is indeed followed by several alternative implementations) is a clever Just In Time-Compiler (JIT), which preserves all the dynamicness but exploits the fact that most Python programs make little use of that dynamicness by recognizing the most common paths at runtime and optimizing for these. Such complex programs are again not written in asm.

Comment: Many folks call C "Portable Assembly Language".

Comment: Nuitka is compiling the Python code as a C code is. It "converts" Python code into C code and then compile it (to exe) as it would be a C code. It is ~1,5x faster in my use cases.

Answer (score 6):

Native code isn't a magic make-it-go-faster operation. The language semantics really dictate quite a bit about how fast (or not) a language is. (For instance, erlang compiled to native code via Hipe is still fairly slow).