# Disadvantage of bootstrapping?

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages

I have seen many links on bootstrapping, I was wondering what are the main drawbacks of bootstrapping a compiler for a language say X using C programming instead of using assembly language? I was wondering if using C would restrict whatever I do to a 'C' like assembly language creation (i.e how C's compiler does it).

For example whatever I write in Python will eventually be taken care by CPython, making it eventually in a C like manner in the hardware - which might not be optimum?

Of course C is probably very good language, but for some other general language it might not be so. Wouldn't bootstrapping eventually have some bottlenecks, restrictions specific to the language I use for making a bootstrapping compiler? Like machine code generation would be like how C generates the code and not some random manner.

Main reason for using C is that it does a good job of mapping our code to machine language but it not be as good as assembly right? So C has some performance problems, now I use C to create a  compiler for another language, so I have to pass on those performance issues right? After all C doesn't do a 1-1 mapping to assembly - hope you get my question.

Comment: The myth that "higher level languages can't be as good as assembly" has been thoroughly debunked for 20 years at least, maybe 30 years. Also, performance problems are likely to come from your algorithm and implementation, not from the limitations of a specific language (do you have a specific case where "C has performance problems", or are you just wondering what-if?).

Comment: I am not an expert so I am in the 'what if' category . 
But my doubt is whether a compiler just uses C's string parsing features and create a ASSEMBLY like mapping for the new programming language . Hence C's other inbuilt features are not even touched upon .

Comment: That depends on what you actually *do* in the programming language; but it is quite possible to use C as a set of macros for  assembly.

Comment: Yes that is precisely what I was thinking. It seems the main purpose of using C as a compiler is that it has a very good set of macros for assembly and only basics of the language are required .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We've had a very similar question before, asking for a [Python interpreter in assembly language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727351/python-implemented-in-assembly). All of these apply to compilers as well: It's an incredible effort (so much that it's pretty much impossible to get anything of this size done), it makes maintaince cost explode, it buys you very very little if it helps at all - in *at least* 2/3 of all cases, it will be actively harmful because none of us can beat a modern C compiler.

And then there's another problem with your reasoning: While we *do* want our compilers to be done fast to make the middle part of the write-compile-debug cycle less annoying and time-wasting, the *performance* of the compiler doesn't affect the performance of the compiled program - and the latter (specifically, the best runtime performance practically possible) is usually more important. And for that, you need lots of very complex algorithms doing very clever optimizations. As said before, a large *interpreter* is already very very hard to impossible in assembly language. Doing all these optimizations is even harder.

Oh, and while we're at it: Bootstrapping can actually lead to **better** performance. The [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) project implements Python in (a subset of) Python. Must be godawful slow, you say? **Wrong!** It can run nearly all programs faster than CPython, which is written in C (which maps about as well to assembly as possible) and was optimized by very clever people over the course of many many years. Often, it needs only a fraction of the time needed. Granted, they win by using a Just In Time compiler, which is by its nature well-suited to optimizing the heck out of dynamic languages. But even the non-JIT version, a regular interpreter, is often less than 2 times slower than CPython. See the [PyPy speed center](http://speed.pypy.org/comparison/?exe=3%2B490%2C2%2B472&ben=1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%2C11%2C12%2C13%2C14%2C15%2C16%2C17%2C18%2C19%2C20&env=1&hor=false&bas=2%2B472&chart=relative+bars).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are some cases where mapping a feature of your language onto a similar feature of C will cost you. Two examples:

If you implement a *YourLang* function call as a C function call---that is, you're naively using the C/native stack---you lose the ability to support deep recursion, proper tail recursion, continuations, and possibly stack inspection. (Or at least, you have to think harder about them.)

If you map a single *YourLang* thread to a single POSIX/Windows/whatever thread, you won't be able to support massive concurrency like Erlang.

That doesn't mean you can't write your interpreter or compiler and runtime in C, though.